# Fatal error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found in Codeigniter.php

Tags: codeigniter

I have a problem when I call a function/controller

```
$route['admin/refresh_rss'] = "index.php/rss/index";
```

I read the problem is about the config/database.php, but, all is OK, the page load correctly, but when I want execute the controller, show Fatal Error

Comment: is that $route['admin/refresh_rss'] is the default route?

Comment: There are three reserved routes: 1.) $route['default_controller'] = 'welcome'; 2.) $route['404_override'] = ''; 3.) $route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When configuring routes in CodeIgniter, the path does not require the `index.php` part.

In this case it's going to try and look for the controller 'Index.php', the action 'rss' and pass through the parameter 'index'.

You should change your route to be:

```
$route['admin/refresh_rss'] = "rss/index";
```

**Edit** Here's the [CodeIgniter routing manual](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)